# Color a pixel in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I need to color a pixel in an image. I use opencv and python.
I tried `img[x,y]=[255 255 255]` to color a `pixel(x,y)` but it wont work :(

Is there is any mistake in this?
Can you suggest any method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

`img[x,y]=[255, 255, 255]` is wrong  because opencv img[a,b] is a matrics then you need to change x,y then you must use img[y,x]

actualy mistake in the order of x,y 
 if you want to change color of point x,y use this >>  `img[y,x] = color`

Answer (score 5):

Try it with comma's between the 255's:

```
img[y,x]=[255, 255, 255]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, just change it to load your own image:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("C:\calibrate\chess\color001.jpg", cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

## Make pixels row and column 300-400 black
img[300:400,300:400] = (0,0,0)

cv2.imshow('title',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: the code is   (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt) .  here (x,y) is a center point.I want to color the center point .so  I use img[x,y] .Is this  wrg? how can I represent the center point?

Comment: First try if my code is working for you to color pixels. Than you can say that this has answered you question. The other question -> print out the x,y coordinates and check if they are what you would expect. Perhaps 1 pxl is to small to see.

Comment: Ur code is wrking to color a block of pixels.I print x,y .The o/p is(97,417).It is x,y coordiante of a pixel.Am i ryt? I need to color a point    img[97,417]=(0,0,0). For tat It is not wrking :(

Comment: You probably need to use img[417,97]=(0,0,0)

Comment: It shows the following error msg :  "  img[417,97]=(0,0,0)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. "

Comment: This is your 3th question in a single stackoverflow question. If you get such an error msg, just search with google and try to understand why it is giving this error. If you can't find the answer, post a new question with some code, such that we don't need to guess what's causing this error.